# Python: Cannot find an internal module

Tags: python, flask

I am creating a python api using flask and gunicorn. The file structure looks like :

```
API
|-__init__.py
|-app.py
|-script.py
|-...
|-internal
   |-utils.py
   |-recorder.py
   |-submitter.py
   |-consts.py
   |-__init__.py
   |-setup.py
```

Internal is supposed to an internal module and needs to be imported in script.py/app.py When I try to do this :

```
from internal.utils import check_email, get_log_file_path
from internal.submitter import run_task
from internal.recorder import get_num_processing_jobs, was_processed, get_job_status
from internal import consts
```

but I am getting an error when I start the server :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'internal'

Is there something that I am missing to access these files in the app.py or script.py
Any leads would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please show your PYTHONPATH, may you need change it to PYTHONPATH={whereis app.py}

Comment: use relative import https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/

Comment: What does your `__init__.py` file have?